# Google Cloud Functions: error deploying, main.py doesn't exist

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Deploying Google Cloud Functions from the local system fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist
```

I've used the console UI to check the contents of the package that was uploaded in the failed deployment and the *file is present*. The package was created using the `gcloud` CLI:

```
gcloud functions deploy <redacted> \
    --trigger-http \
    --runtime=python37 \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --project=<redacted> \
    --entry-point=<redacted>
```

For context, the same project was deployed successfully multiple times by several people but started failing for everyone new that checked it out after a specific date.

Comment: Did you follow the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart) to get your first deployment to work?  Please edit the question to show the contents of your project directories, and the directory where you ran gcloud.

Comment: Yep, the project had previously been deployed successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our case, this was because of invalid credentials, i.e. the JSON file passed to `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name` was missing. Confusingly, the error doesn't mention anything about security, credentials or that missing file.

Secrets are not in version control and the shared vault had a stale file that did not match the path provided in the python script. This was fixed once the credentials were corrected.

We managed to isolate the problem to the authenticated call by successfully deploying 'dumb' functions (return a string) and then incrementally adding back functionality until it broke.

Comment: This seems like a bug with Cloud Functions. I've filed an issue internally, thanks!

Comment: @DustinIngram Thank you! 

Comment: I got into this error when running `main.py` led to a `FileNotFound` exception. Specifically, `main.py` imported from `settings.py`, which included `with open('foo') as f:`, where `'foo'` was a file that no longer existed. So unlike in @AlexCiminian's case, the exception wasn't raised from Google API code; it was standard-library Python that had nothing to do with credentials. For @DustinIngram: SDK 251.0.0, beta 2019.05.17.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in my application in Node.js, basically I identified that the `.gcloudignore` file it invokes the `.gitignore` of the project, so if your function is in a skipped folder it simply does not find, then just remove the line `#! Include : .gitignore` file `.gcloudignore`